# Pool.map hangs after 4 iterations

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm new to Python and multiprocessing. I wanted to batch convert a bunch of files, so I figured I'd try out multiprocessing. The Pool and map() concepts seemed simple enough, but it doesn't seem to work. I have reduced it to a test program below, but the gist of it is: it will go through 4 iterations (per process in Pool) and hang after that.  Here's the test code:

```
import multiprocessing, logging
import os
import sys

mpl = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr()
mpl.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def chill(t):
    cmd  = '/bin/sleep'
    args = (cmd,str(t))
    print >>sys.stderr, os.getpid(), args
    os.execv(cmd, args)

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    times = [ 1 ] * 100
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(1)  # change this for more processes
    pool.map(chill, times)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

When I run it, it hangs after the 4th iteration. Increasing the number of processes just makes it hang at 4x the number of processes.  What's magical about this "4", and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `os.execv` replaces the child process. You don't want to do that. Try `subprocess.call(['/bin/sleep', str(t)])`.

Comment: But then it should die after the first call, no?

Comment: I'm not sure, there may be some recovery protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `os.execv` replaces the child process so the regular handshake between parent and child is lost. `Pool.map()` sends arguments to be processed in chunks. If the process exits unexpectedly, mp restarts the process and sends another chunk. You've probably uncovered a bug in the multiprocessing module because it continues to send data to process in this abnormal condition and then hangs waiting for task completions that will never arrive.

The solution is to use a function such as `subprocess.call` to do a full fork and exec of the code you want to run. This leaves the child process in tact and able to pass results back to the parent.

The issue is seen more clearly with a few changes to the test program.

```
import multiprocessing, logging
import os
import sys
import subprocess as subp

mpl = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr()
mpl.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def chill(args):
    i, t = args
    cmd  = '/bin/sleep'
    args = (cmd,str(t))
    print >>sys.stderr, i, os.getpid(), args
    os.execv(cmd, args)
#    subp.call(['/bin/sleep', str(t)])

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    times = [(i,1) for i in range(100)]
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(1)  # change this for more processes
    pool.map(chill, times)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

map has broken the work into 4 chunks and then hangs after the last one

```
[INFO/PoolWorker-1] child process calling self.run()
0 9204 ('/bin/sleep', '1')
[INFO/PoolWorker-2] child process calling self.run()
25 9208 ('/bin/sleep', '1')
[INFO/PoolWorker-3] child process calling self.run()
50 9209 ('/bin/sleep', '1')
[INFO/PoolWorker-4] child process calling self.run()
75 9210 ('/bin/sleep', '1')
[INFO/PoolWorker-5] child process calling self.run()
```

Comment: I'm new to Python, but I had assumed "multiprocessing" would do a fork/join (and the "pool.join()" sort of seemed to reinforce this impression). If it's not doing a fork/join, then it makes sense that execv() would cause problems. But the 4 subprocesses threw me for a loop; since it seemed to work, I didn't think the execv() was a problem

Comment: In Linux, multiprocessing does a fork to create its children. The problem is that you did an exec without an additional fork so the child's multiprocessing.Pool protocol was lost. In my opinion, the multiprocessing parent should have thrown an exception when from its perspective the child had gone completely bonkers. Otherwise, we're left guesssing.